# package private member variables in a junit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am working on a project where all the member variables of the junit tests are declared as package private.

For example :

```
public class MyTest {

    MyObject someObject;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        someObject = new MyObject();
    }
}
```

Instead of :

```
public class MyTest {

    private MyObject someObject;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        someObject = new MyObject();
    }
}
```

I know the guy that originally wrote the tests is generally knowledgeable, attends a lot of conferences, has read many books. So I am wondering where he might have picked this up and what could be the rationale behind this ?

Comment: Is the someObject field being used by another class elsewhere?

Comment: no, and he does this for all the member variables

Comment: Why not ask the developer who wrote this

Comment: I've voted to close this question as "not constructive". There is no definitive correct answer and so debate will ensue about why this particular developer has chosen to do this. I suggest you follow @Learner's advice and take this up with the developer in question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a style thing as much as anything else.  Some people tend to make things private by default and then open up the scope as they require.  Perhaps the IDE he used defaulted to package private.  It's really kind of hard to answer why someone may have done it like that.

I'd say in this case, you'd be better off it being private.  But without seeing the rest of the code it's hard to say.  If it's being used from elsewhere then perhaps you'd consider creating a base test class that other tests extends to capture some common functionality.  In that case you'd give is a name to reflect it's purpose.

Comment: We use the same IDE, so no it's definitely deliberate, there's no inheritance being used anywhere.

Comment: Sometimes you can change these things at the developer level.  For instance we could share the same IDE but I favour private final fields for immutibility reasons.  I'd still stick with going for private in this case.  Package private could lead to dependencies between two classes where you might not want it.